# Table formating

Tags: tables, fonts, scale

To whom it may concern:

I am using Overleaf. The table below is too wide for the page. I am thinking of reducing the scale/font for the entire table in one go unless there is a better way.

Thank you for any guidance.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
\caption{Properties of titanium and its alloys}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline 
         \textbf{Category}&  \textbf{Chemical Composition [Weight \%]}&  \textbf{Hardness [HV]}&  \textbf{YS [MPa]}&  \textbf{TS [MPa]}&  \textbf{E [GPa]}& \textbf{Tbeta [Deg C]}\\ \hline 
         \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Alpha}\\ \hline 
         Hi purity Ti&  99.98 Ti&  
100&  140&  235&  100 - 145& 882\\ \hline 
         CP-Ti-Grade 1&  0.2Fe - 0.18O 99.62 Ti&  120&  170 - 310&  240&  -& 890\\ \hline 
         CP-Ti-Grade 4&  0.5Fe - 0.4O 99.1 Ti&  260&  480 - 655&  550&  100 - 120& 950\\ \hline 
         Alloy Grade 6&  Ti-5Al-2.5Sn&  300&  829&  861&  109& 1040\\ \hline 
         \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Near Alpha}\\ \hline 
         Ti-6-2-4-2-S&  Ti-6Al-2Sn-4Zr-2Mo-0.1Si&  340&  990&  1010&  114& 995\\ \hline 
         TIMETAL 1100&  Ti-6Al-2.7Sn-4Zr-0.4Mo-0.4Si&  -&  900 - 950&  1010 - 1050&  112& 1010\\ \hline 
         TIMETAL 685&  Ti-6Al-5Zr-0.5Mo-0.25Si&  -&  850 - 910&  990 - 1020&  120& 1020\\ \hline
 \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Alpha + Beta}\\\hline
 Ti-6-4& Ti-6Al-4V& 300 - 400& 800 - 1100& 900 - 1200& 110 - 140&995\\\hline
 Ti-6-6-2& Ti-6Al-6V-2Sn& 300 - 400& 950 - 1050& 1000 - 1100& 110 - 117&945\\\hline
 Ti-6-2-4-6& Ti-6Al-2Sn-4Zr-6Mo& 300 - 400& 1000 - 1100& 1100 - 1200& 114&940\\\hline
 Ti-17& Ti-5Al-2Sn-2Zr-4Mo-4Cr& 400& 1050& 1100 - 1250& 112&890\\\hline
 \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Near-Beta}\\\hline
 SP 700& Ti-4.5Al-3V-2Mo-2Fe& 300 - 500& 900& 960& 110&900\\\hline
 Beta 111& Ti-11.5Mo-6Zr-4.5Sn& 250 - 450& 800 - 1200& 900 - 1300& 83 - 103&760\\\hline
 Beta C& Ti-3Al-8V-6Cr-4Mo-4Zr& 300 - 450& 800 - 1200& 900 - 1300& 86 - 115&795\\\hline
 Ti-10-2-3& Ti-10V-2Fe-3Al& 300 - 470& 1000 - 1200& 1000 - 1400& 110&800\\\hline
 Ti-15-3& Ti-15V-3Cr-3Al-3Sn& 300 - 450& 800 - 1000& 800 - 1000& 80 - 100&760\\\hline
 \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Tbeta - Beta transus temperature; YS - Yield strength; TS - Tensile Strength; E - Elastic modulus.}\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    
  \label{tab:Properties of titanium and its alloys}%    
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, please remember that always keep `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Apologies I do not know what you mean by MWE and \documentclass to \end{document}. Are you saying I should have had a \begin{document} and then an \end{document} in the above code?

Comment: He asked for a compilable LaTeX code fragment that is minimal in terms of length.

Comment: You could use `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{tabular from above}` unless it is too small for your purpose.

Comment: @Arne _please_ don't suggest applying scaling to tables, it should only be done as a last resort, and preferably not even then.

Comment: @GS76 Please refer https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: @David Carlisle I was not aware of this no go. Can you give me a reference that explains the reasons behind this? I found it quite handy in case the font is not getting too small (probably below `footnotesize` or `tiny`, depending on the purpose).

Comment: if you search this site for resizebox you will find such a comment under almost every tabular from someone. You have already seen it makes arbitrarily small fonts with no warning but even when larger, it produces inconsistent font sizes and rule widths. better you choose a named font size such as `\small` or format the table so it fits. @Arne